# How to stop a script totally with Keyboard Interrupt

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cherrypy, gpio

I have a python script running cherrypy server. When I pressed CTRL+C, it stops the server but not the function in the script. The function will continue to print the sensor value and i can't stop it regardless of how many times i press CTRL+C. How can I make sure CTRL+C can stop all (both server and the function)?

Here is my full script: http://pastebin.com/yKLt3mJN

This is the function i am trying to stop:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def sensor(self):

    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os

    DEBUG = 1
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)

    def RCtime (RCpin):
        reading = 0
        GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.output(RCpin, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)

        GPIO.setup(RCpin, GPIO.IN)
        # This takes about 1 millisecond per loop cycle
        while (GPIO.input(RCpin) == GPIO.LOW):
            reading += 1
        return reading

    while True:
        sensorvalue= RCtime(12)

        if sensorvalue > 1000:
            print "switch on light"
            GPIO.output(11, True) #switch on
            lightstate ="On"
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print "switch off light"
            GPIO.output(11, False) #switch off
            lightstate ="Off"
            time.sleep(1)

        print sensorvalue # Read RC timing using BCM pin #18, physical pin 12

    return lightstate
```

If i run the function alone, i can stop it.

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "RCtime.py", line 25, in <module>
    print RCtime(18) # Read RC timing using pin #18
  File "RCtime.py", line 16, in RCtime
    time.sleep(0.1)
  KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to catch the Ctrl+C in Python so that you can correctly terminate the program and safely exit by the use of exit(0) or exit(1).

Note that:

exit(0) means a clean exit without any errors / problems

exit(1) means there was some issue / error / problem and that is why the program is exiting.

e.g

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import signal
import sys

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
# sleep until a signal is received
signal.pause()
```

Comment: Do you mean i can just add this into my existing script? or put in under the function `sensor`?

Comment: I get this
  `File "pilldispense5.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Control:
  File "pilldispense5.py", line 281, in Control
    sleep.pause()
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined`

Comment: I've just edited, indeed it should be signal.pause(), for more info I recommend you to look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.htm

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try, although it shouldn't be the way you stop the script all the time, is find out the process id of the server using

```
ps aux | grep <name of what you executed to start the server>
```

and then `kill -15 <pid>`.